# How to set up iPhone screen grid in CorelDraw

Tags: page-layout, corel-draw, dpi, interface-design, ios

I use CorelDraw for creating wireframe layouts for iOS app UI. For this I need to set up a rectangle as following, to act as screen boundary:

Size in pixels: **640 x 1136px**

Size when unit changed to millimeters: **51.7 x 90.4mm**

This can help realistic pixel-level control, and at the same time printing on a paper in actual size. How do I achieve this?

I tried setting document DPI to 326, which is iPhone's PPI, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake calculating the size in centímeters. According to the pixel size you are providing, you are refering to the Iphone 5, which have 4" in diagonal (10.16cm) https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/, wich will be more or less 4.98x8.85 cm.

But in any case, the best workflow would be changing the document unit from cm to pixels (Design > Prepare page), and you can asign the 640x1136 px size directly (1920x1080 px for newer iphone 6 plus), and just asigning the 326 ppi (or 401 ppi) for the printed sample.

Comment: Thanks. The original question was intended for iPhone 5 only, where there seems to be a mistake in physical dimensions. I got correct printable size now. However, how did you get the physical screen size? I can always measure, but a reference could be useful.

Comment: I used some math.

Comment: 1) Take the relationship 640/1136 2) Do some pitagoras law a2+b2=c2 1304"px" in diagonal 3) Rule of thirds if 1304=4" then 640=x 4*640/1136 =1.98 inch

Comment: (Rule of three, not thirds... that is on photography :oP)